# Android - Sync a file from one device to multiple contacts devices via TCP/IP

Tags: android, networking, tcp, ip, synchronization

Okay, I am trying to create an app that once I make changes to a file it will sync to the devices of the contacts that I have selected. Is there a way to: when the contacts are selected get the IP address' of each contact and open a port and sync the files to all devices?

Answer (score 2):

I guess it is impossible because you cannot infer the IP address from the contact. Also you cannot store this info with a contact, because usually smartphones are assigned by an operator with dynamic IP addresses that change frequently.

Comment: hrm...i have two ideas
1) use an SMS message to deliver the ip:port
2) Use SIP, turn off mic, and use it to transfer the file that way...Not too familiar with SIP though. Would this be a practical solution? or is the transfer rate extremely slow? will do some searching on this now also...

Comment: The following scheme is possible with all variations. You have a server in the Internet. Your clients (smartphones) connect to this server (they are online now). Now the server knows IP addresses of its clients. So it can forward to your smartphone (that wants to send files) the information about the IP addresses of clients.